# Prevent application from requesting password on MacOS

Tags: macos, password, permission

Is there a way to prevent applications from requesting for password forever? I found lot of references to give applications root permission so they won't prompt for password. But I don't want to give any permission, I just want to deny all requests for password. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** The application I'm talking about is Slack. It works great, but every time I open it and sometimes even after it's opened, it keeps requesting password to install helper tools. I don't want it to install anything and I just don't want it to keep asking me every time.

Comment: You might want to add at least one or two example apps and if you are launching from a user account with Admin privileges or not.

Comment: @SteveChambers Updated my question

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, any app which is *routinely asking to escalate permissions* is either **badly written** or **suspect**, or is an admin-type tool *which should be run intentionally from an already-elevated user condition at all times*.

If this is supposedly an app aimed at everyday users, and it's *routinely* needing escalation, that indicates it's needing to change preferences or permissions in a way which violates the most basic tenets of security and/or sandboxing to a degree which would worry me until I determined exactly what the offending subprocess(es) was or were, why this caused continual escalation, and if that was either acceptable to me or defensible in some manner.

So for me, the answer would ***start*** with "what, why and how" is causing the escalation, and only *after* nailing that down *really* solidly would I consider undertaking setting this app to always run elevated, which honestly is a simple thing to do in Terminal, but... it's very much a non-trivial, only do it when both essential and you are dead sure it's safe and appropriate way to go.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I'm a bit paranoid when it comes to giving permission. I have edited my question to give an example of an app I'm talking about. Even though its a well known app, I'm still not okay with giving permission. Unfortunately I have to use the application everyday :(

Comment: That's really concerning to me - I use Slack on Mac OS routinely, and have not had it request escalation. I think this should be posted to Slack's support as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the app in question happens to be slack, you happen to be an admin, and you happen to just want it to shut up... change who owns the app so that it can update itself.

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME /Applications/Slack.app
```